# How to convert an invalid date string to Javascript date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I fetch invalid date strings from the REST API but i may not fix the REST API. How can i format an invalid date strings like that "20180517T010237" ?

I tried to use moment for that, but i couldnt succeed.

```
let date = moment("20180517T010237", "YYYY-MM-DD T HH.mm.ss").toDate();
```

is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second string you pass [`moment`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) is the format of the string you're parsing. Your format string has `-` and spaces that aren't in your input. Remove them:

```
let date = moment("20180517T010237", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss").toDate();
```

Note that it will be parsed in local time. If you want UTC instead, use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

```
let date = moment.utc("20180517T010237", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss").toDate();
```

Example:

```js
let date = moment("20180517T010237", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss").toDate();
console.log(date);

date = moment.utc("20180517T010237", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss").toDate();
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `20180517T010237` is recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), no need use  [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: @VincenzoC - Yeah, I suppose that is ISO-8601, so one of the few string formats that it's okay to use the non-format version with.

Comment: Thanx @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Thanx @VincenzoC

Comment: can i convert it back too with moment.js?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder exactly, even OP code parse input correctly (see [Forgiving Mode](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/forgiving-mode/)), for me the question was unclear, but it seems that the OP is fine with answer (that also got a lot of upvotes!), so everything is fine :)

Comment: @VincenzoC - More upvotes than it really deserves. :-) But it's like that with simple answers sometimes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can i convert it back to the first format too?

Comment: @AdamJungen - Date objects have no format. Format is a *string* concept. To get a string a particular format for a date, you'd use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder works like a charm, thanx. Your answer deserves upvotes well.